# Get parents recursive in right order for deletion from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, parent, children

I have an table structure like this

```
mysql> SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| id    | name       | parent_id |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 15790 | Test       |         0 |
| 15791 | Test2      |         0 |
| 16079 | Subtest    |     15790 |
| 16080 | Subtest 2  |     15790 |
| 16081 | Subsubtest |     16079 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

Now I want to look up the parent for every children and sibling and give it back in the right order for deletion.

So my output in this case would be:

```
Array
(
  16081,
  16080,
  16079,
  15791,
  15790
)
```

I can't delete just by reversing the parent ids, because this should be solid walking back the tree.

Also I am not able/allowed to change the structure of the table. So building kind of an index is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with a trigger?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "right order for deletion"?

Comment: @KeithRandall Of course: All the sub-categories (and their siblings) have to be deleted *before* their parent categories. Nothing spectacular but I wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @DanLee, is this due to a foreign-key constraint error when you try to delete a row before its children?

Comment: What is the criteria that would be used in a select statement? Is the idea that you are going to delete a record and you need to check for and delete any children, grandchildren, etc? Will there be grandchildren and below?

Comment: The problem is a based on poor database design; there are other dependencies to the categories. But on the other side they have foreign-key constraints to other tables, so they have to be deleted in the right sort order (*dont blame it on me* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't have access to `TRUNCATE`, `SET` (so you could do `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`), `ALTER`, etc. etc., and absolutely ***must*** use a script:

Since the question is tagged with `php`, this should do the trick:

```
function reversetree($src_arr, $currentid = 0)
{
    $cats = array();
    foreach($src_arr as $id => $parent)
    {   
        if($parent == $currentid)
        {
            $cats[] = $id;
            $cats = array_merge($cats, reversetree($src_arr, $id));
        }
    }
    return !$currentid ? array_reverse($cats) : $cats;
}

$rs = array();
foreach($pdo->query('SELECT id, parent_id FROM categories') as $row)
    $rs[$row['id']] = $row['parent_id'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = ?');

$pdo->beginTransaction();
foreach(reversetree($rs) as $v)
    $stmt->execute(array($v));
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you Zane! (you will get your reward as soon as possible)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you need the IDs in a particular order.  You can delete them with a transaction and they will all be deleted simultaneously.

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE ID IN (15790,15791,16079,16080,16081);
```

Comment: This is correct (+1).  But you may need to run the query successive times; out-of-order deletes may result in errors, so the query may need to be run repeatedly.

Comment: Yeah I thought about brute forcing it too, but there are other dependencies somewhere in the dark which I don't want to find out. There are several issues with the database design, which should clearly be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You could add FOREIGN KEY constraint with CASCADE on DELETE. 
The foreign key will point to the same table on the parent id field.

When you delete the parent, all the children (no matter what level) are removed automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to change anything of the table structure. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// housekeeping
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$select = $pdo->prepare(
    "SELECT parent.id AS parent_id, child.id AS child_id
    FROM categories AS parent
    JOIN categories AS child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
    WHERE parent.id = ?"
);
$delete = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = ?');

// deletes $node_id, deletes its children first if required
function delete_node($node_id){
    $select->execute( array($node_id) );
    $children = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if (count($children) !== 0) { // if 0, then the category does not exist, or it has no child
        foreach ($children as $child) { // call delete_node() recursively on each child
            delete_node ($child[1]);
        }
    }
    $delete->execute( array($node_id) ); // then delete this node (or do nothing if $node_id does not exist)
}


// to delete one category and all its sub-categories

delete_node(15790);

// to delete all contents

$allTopLevel = $pdo->exec('SELECT id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
foreach ($allTopLevel as $node) {
    delete_node($node[0]);
}
```

*Not* tested, not even sure if it "compiles", but you get the idea. Make sure to lock the table (or start a transaction) before calling `delete_node()`.

Comment: The problem is the excessive use of queries, one should be enough to build an index (see Zanes reply). But thanks for your time though, and I am sure this one would work too :)

Comment: Absolutely true, I just felt like doing it recursively, as the tag suggests. Zane Bien's code performs much quicker.

Comment: @DanLee Although `id` and `parent_id` being indexed, MySQL should be able to work from memory only. But still, this solution is Bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't help much, because SQL is not my thing. But perhaps someone could transfer java pseudo code to the solution

```
delete(table.getFirstRow().get(id));

delete(id_a){
    for(data_set : table)
        if(data_set.get(parent_id) == id_a)delete(data_set.get(id));
    }
    table.remove(id_a);
}
```

edit: no iteration about elements? So something like this?

```
delete(list){
    if(list.size() == 0)return;
    idList = list.getAll(id);
    plist = table.getAllWhichEquals(parent_id, idList);
    delete(plist);
    table.remove(idList);
}
```

ah, forget it, i'm deleting not all at the same time, was just a try ^^

Comment: That would be great if it were possible to iterate over records; but SQL is a single pass.